# NodeJs Express setting a View to see folder's content rendered as html

Tags: node.js, express

Having this code in my `server.js`

```
...
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

// Set the view directory to /views
app.set("views", __dirname);

http.createServer(app).listen(9001);
...
```

I'm excepting by going here `":9001/myhtml.html"` to see my content. But instead I see:

```
Cannot GET /myhtml.html
```

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/static_dir")))`

See http://expressjs.com/faq.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to visually *see* list of files in the folder, you should also use `express.directory`

```
        app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/static_dir")))
        app.use(express.directory(path.join(__dirname, "/static_dir")))
```